# Advice on type of database and software for research on genetic diversity of crops

Tags: phylogenetics, database

for a research project I am evaluating the potential of Robusta coffee genetic resources in the tropic region of Africa. Different ex-situ genetic lines will be mapped as well as chemical, morphological and organoleptic analysis of the coffee beans.

I am looking for a type of database and software that would be well suited for this type of dataset. Are there any genetic database programs out there that allow you to merge other datasets (like plant descriptors or cupping profiles)? Or should I look the other way around and use a database that easily links with genetic fingerprint software?

Thank you,
Robrecht

Comment: This question is more likely to be considered on-topic in SE Bioinformatics as it seems mainly about the choice of software. I suggest deleting and reposting, but in your repost you should specify what you think a database program is — i.e. what data you wish to store and what processing of the data you are hoping external programs to do. Your computation skills will also be of relevance. You need to be more concrete.

Comment: ok thank you David, I will do that.

Comment: I don't know whether this is relevant for you, but I see here an example of tropical crops database that says it is made using the generalist mySQL system: https://tropgenedb.cirad.fr/tropgene/JSP/presentation.jsp

Comment: Also, much coffee research is published in Portuguese

Comment: Thank you for the advice.